# How to have nested logical and/or in Firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase database rule to block:

- non-authenticated users
- users trying to create data for some other user
- I also want to prevent updating data.I need this code for that:

  ```
  !data.exists() || !newData.exists()
  ```

This is currently how it looks:

```
"rules": {
"orders": {
  "$order":{
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.admin === true",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === newData.child('userID').val()" // check the incoming data's userID value here if sender is same. or someone can send orders with other peoples ids. also anyone can send an order with id 123 but only if it doesnt exist. so they cannot update anyones order. is this safe enough?
  },
  ".indexOn": "userID"
}
```

}

1. How am I supposed to include this "||" operator in my logical expression for the ".write" rules?
2. I am not able to delete data. Is it because Im checking the newData's child in the security rules and there is no newData when using ".remove()" in the app? If that is the case, how does write and delete rules in the same line work?

Comment: The docs suggest you can use both && and ||.  What specific problem are you having?  Are you using the auth simulator to figure out why your rules don't work the way you expect?

Comment: Please replace the picture of the rules with the actual rules as text. Having the rules as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual rules and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson But I need to somehow contain "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()" in a parenthesis or something and add to the expression with a logical and. If I just place it near this logical expression, "!newData.exists()" will allow access to all data because it is after a ||

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a weird issue that I could not use parantheses at first but it is now working. I created an || between two expressions

First expression is for write:

```
(auth != null && newData.exists() && auth.uid === newData.child('userID').val() && !data.exists())
```

Here "newData.exists()" in the expression tells us there is an incoming data ( write/update operation) and "!data.exists()" blocks updating data.

Second expression is for deleting rules:

```
(!newData.exists() && auth != null && auth.uid === data.child('userID').val()
```

Here "!newData.exists()" says that there is no new data so this is a delete operation, and the next part makes sure everyone can only delete their own data.

So now the code looks like this:

```
"rules": {
"orders": {
  "$order":{
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.admin === true",
    ".write": "(auth != null && newData.exists() && auth.uid === newData.child('userID').val() && !data.exists()) || (!newData.exists() && auth != null && auth.uid === data.child('userID').val())"
  },
  ".indexOn": "userID"
},
```

}